# Illustrator divide and create new shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am new to illustrator and I can't work this out. I am trying to draw a missile and I need to create a new nose cone section. I have made a path in blue here where I want to divide and create a new nose piece shape at that divide. Whats the best way to do this? any help would be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make certain the blue path extends *past* the edges of the underlying shape.

Select the shape and the blue line...

Click the `Divide` button on the **PathFinder Panel**. 
The shape will be "cut" (i.e. "divided") by the path on top of it.

`Object > Ungroup` may be necessary after Pathfinder.

Comment: got it - yeah my path didn't extend far enough. Thank you!